# Magento event to observe shipment creation, not invoice

Tags: extensions, event-observer, shipment

I'm trying to send a text message right after shipment was created in admin panel. I'm observing `sales_order_shipment_save_after` which works fine. The problem is this event fires on invoice creation too.

I couldn't find the right event for observing only shipment creation. Any suggestion?

I'm on 1.9.2.1.

[EDIT]

I listed all events by adding `Mage::log` in `dispatchEvent` method in `app/Mage.php`. These are the ones which seem related (and I didn't try them already):

```
sales_order_shipment_save_commit_after
controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_save
core_copy_fieldset_sales_convert_order_to_shipment
```

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 2):

With `sales_order_shipment_save_commit_after` you will run into the same issue. The other mentioned events do not tell if the shipment was/will be created successfully.

Probably the `sales_order_shipment_save_after` event is just fine, but you miss a point: The `save()` method is not only called on *create* operations but also on *update*. In your case, I guess, the latter fires on invoice creation.

Stick with the event and test in your observer method whether the shipment was just created or not:

```
// Observer::shipmentSaveAfter()
if ($observer->getShipment()->getOrigData('entity_id')) {
    // shipment updated, do nothing
    return;
}

// shipment new, send text message
```

This is not 100% reliable though as the *original data* is populated on load and as such not necessarily during multiple calls to the `save()` method.

Alternatively you could register a flag on `sales_order_shipment_save_before`:

```
// Observer::shipmentSaveBefore()
if ($observer->getShipment()->isObjectNew()) {
    Mage::register('send_shipment_message', true);
}


// Observer::shipmentSaveAfter()
if (!Mage::registry('send_shipment_message')) {
    // shipment updated, do nothing
    return;
}

Mage::unregister('send_shipment_message');
// shipment new, send text message
```

Comment: Neither worked. After saving invoice, both `sales_order_shipment_save_before` and `sales_order_shipment_save_after` has been called and `$observer->getShipment()` is a new object with no `entity_id`.

Comment: Did you find the way?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare created_at and updated_at time. For new shipment created_at == updated_at